# CS8176: Iterators cannot have by-reference locals

Tags: c#, ref, enumerator

Is there real reason for this error in given code, or just *It could go wrong in general usage where the reference would be needed across interator steps* (which is not true in this case)?

```
IEnumerable<string> EnumerateStatic()
{
    foreach (int i in dict.Values)
    {
        ref var p = ref props[i]; //< CS8176: Iterators cannot have by-reference locals
        int next = p.next;
        yield return p.name;
        while (next >= 0)
        {
            p = ref props[next];
            next = p.next;
            yield return p.name;
        }
    }
}

struct Prop
{
    public string name;
    public int next;
    // some more fields like Func<...> read, Action<..> write, int kind
}
Prop[] props;
Dictionary<string, int> dict;
```

`dict` is name-index map, case-insensitive
`Prop.next` is to *point-to* next node to be iterated over (-1 as terminator; because `dict` is case-insensitive and this *linked-list* was added to resolve conflicts by case-sensitive search with fallback to first).

I see two options now:

1. Implement custom iterator/enumerator, mscs/Roslyn is just not good enough now to see well and do its job. *(No blame here, I can understand, not so important feature.)*
2. Drop the optimisation and just index it twice (once for `name` and second time for `next`). Maybe the compiler will get it and produce optimal machine code anyway. *(I am creating scripting engine for Unity, this really is performance critical. Maybe it just checks the bounds once and uses ref/pointer-like access with no cost next time.)*

And maybe 3. (2b, 2+1/2) Just copy the struct *(32B on x64, three object references and two integers, but may grow, cannot see future)*. Probably not good solution (I either care and write the iterator or it is as good as 2.)

**What I do understand:**

The `ref var p` cannot live after `yield return`, because the compiler is constructing the iterator - a state machine, the `ref` cannot be passed to next `IEnumerator.MoveNext()`. But that is not the case here.

**What I do not understand:**

Why is such a rule enforced, instead of trying to actually generate the iterator/enumerator to see if such `ref var` needs to cross the boundary (which it does not need here). Or any other way to do the job *which looks doable (I do understand that what I imagine is harder to implement and expect answer to be: Roslyn folks have better things to do. Again, no offense, perfectly valid answer.)*

**Expected answers:**

1. Yes, maybe in the future / not worth it (create an Issue - will do if you find it worth it).
2. There is better way (please share, I need solution).

*If you want/need more context, it is for this project: https://github.com/evandisoft/RedOnion/tree/master/RedOnion.ROS/Descriptors/Reflect (Reflected.cs and Members.cs)*

**The reproducible example:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        class Test
        {
            struct Prop
            {
                public string name;
                public int next;
            }
            Prop[] props;
            Dictionary<string, int> dict;
            public IEnumerable<string> Enumerate()
            {
                foreach (int i in dict.Values)
                {
                    ref var p = ref props[i]; //< CS8176: Iterators cannot have by-reference locals
                    int next = p.next;
                    yield return p.name;
                    while (next >= 0)
                    {
                        p = ref props[next];
                        next = p.next;
                        yield return p.name;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler wants to rewrite iterator blocks with locals as fields, to retain the state, and you **cannot** have ref-types as fields. Yes, you're right that it doesn't cross the `yield` so technically it *could* probably be rewritten to re-declare it as-needed, but that makes for *very* complex rules for humans to remember, where simple-looking changes break the code. A blanket "no" is much easier to grok.

The workaround in this scenario (or similarly with `async` methods) is usually a helper method; for example:

```cs
    IEnumerable<string> EnumerateStatic()
    {
        (string value, int next) GetNext(int index)
        {
            ref var p = ref props[index];
            return (p.name, p.next);
        }
        foreach (int i in dict.Values)
        {
            (var name, var next) = GetNext(i);
            yield return name;
            while (next >= 0)
            {
                (name, next) = GetNext(next);
                yield return name;
            }
        }
    }
```

or

```cs
    IEnumerable<string> EnumerateStatic()
    {
        string GetNext(ref int next)
        {
            ref var p = ref props[next];
            next = p.next;
            return p.name;
        }
        foreach (int i in dict.Values)
        {
            var next = i;
            yield return GetNext(ref next);
            while (next >= 0)
            {
                yield return GetNext(ref next);
            }
        }
    }
```

The local function is not bound by the iterator-block rules, so you can use ref-locals.

Comment: @firda that's up to you; I expect it would be closed as "by design", and: I'd support that closure

Comment: I expected it to be *corner-case not worth pursuing now*, but *support that closure*? Ok, I expected *backlog*. (P.S.: I accept, won't even try)

Comment: @firda because the number of cases where the compiler can *prove it* is limited, and it is complex for humans

Answer (score 6):

> the ref cannot be passed to next IEnumerator.MoveNext(). But that is not the case here.

The compiler creates a state machine class to hold the data needed at runtime to continue to the next iteration. It's *that class* that can't contain a ref member.

The compiler *could* detect that the variable is only needed in a limited scope, and not needed to be added to that state class, but as Marc says in their answer, that's an expensive feature for little added benefit. Remember, [features start at -100 points](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericgu/minus-100-points). So you could ask for it, but make sure to explain its use.

For what it's worth, Marc's version is ~4% faster (according to [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/guides/getting-started.html)) for this setup:

```
public class StructArrayAccessBenchmark
{
    struct Prop
    {
        public string name;
        public int next;
    }

    private readonly Prop[] _props = 
    {
        new Prop { name = "1-1", next = 1 }, // 0
        new Prop { name = "1-2", next = -1 }, // 1

        new Prop { name = "2-1", next = 3 }, // 2
        new Prop { name = "2-2", next = 4 }, // 3
        new Prop { name = "2-2", next = -1 }, // 4
    };

    readonly Dictionary<string, int> _dict = new Dictionary<string, int>
    {
        { "1", 0 },
        { "2", 2 },
    };

    private readonly Consumer _consumer = new Consumer();

    // 95ns
    [Benchmark]
    public void EnumerateRefLocalFunction() => enumerateRefLocalFunction().Consume(_consumer);

    // 98ns
    [Benchmark]
    public void Enumerate() => enumerate().Consume(_consumer);

    public IEnumerable<string> enumerateRefLocalFunction()
    {
        (string value, int next) GetNext(int index)
        {
            ref var p = ref _props[index];
            return (p.name, p.next);
        }

        foreach (int i in _dict.Values)
        {
            var (name, next) = GetNext(i);
            yield return name;

            while (next >= 0)
            {
                (name, next) = GetNext(next);
                yield return name;
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> enumerate()
    {
        foreach (int i in _dict.Values)
        {
            var p = _props[i];
            int next = p.next;
            yield return p.name;
            while (next >= 0)
            {
                p = _props[next];
                next = p.next; 
                yield return p.name;
            }
        }
    }
```

Results:

```
|                    Method |      Mean |    Error |   StdDev |
|-------------------------- |----------:|---------:|---------:|
| EnumerateRefLocalFunction |  94.83 ns | 0.138 ns | 0.122 ns |
|                 Enumerate |  98.00 ns | 0.285 ns | 0.238 ns |
```